# Installing Nvidia drivers and CUDA

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I am a beginner on Ubuntu and want to install CUDA on Ubuntu 14.04 for running some parallel code for my projects. But I am stuck at this point.

When I run this command on the terminal

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

It shows

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

It does not even shows my graphics card. But when I run

```
lspci -v
```

It shows a number of details including

```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
!!! Unknown header type 7f
```

Also when I run the 'details' on my operating system, it shows
Processor : Intel® Core™ i5-3337U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 4 
Graphics : Intel® Ivybridge Mobile
OS type : 64-bit

But when I run 'Additional Drivers' on my operating system, it shows
NVIDIA Corporation : GK208M [GeForce GT740M]
Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 352.39 from nvidia-352

When I run the command

```
dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
```

It shows the following output

```
ii  bbswitch-dkms                                         0.7-2ubuntu1                                        amd64        Interface for toggling the power on nVidia Optimus video cards
ii  bumblebee                                             3.2.1-5                                             amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support for Linux
ii  bumblebee-nvidia                                      3.2.1-5                                             amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support using the proprietary NVIDIA driver 
rc  libcuda1-304                                          304.128-0ubuntu0.0.1                                amd64        NVIDIA CUDA runtime library
ii  libcuda1-352                                          352.39-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA CUDA runtime library
rc  nvidia-304                                            304.128-0ubuntu0.0.1                                amd64        NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.128
ii  nvidia-352                                            352.39-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 352.39
ii  nvidia-352-dev                                        352.39-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver development files
ii  nvidia-352-uvm                                        352.39-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-352
rc  nvidia-libopencl1-304                                 304.125-0ubuntu0.0.1                                amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL Driver and ICD Loader library
ii  nvidia-modprobe                                       352.39-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        Load the NVIDIA kernel driver and create device files
rc  nvidia-opencl-icd-304                                 304.128-0ubuntu0.0.1                                amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-352                                 352.39-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA  OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-settings                                       352.39-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  primus                                                0~20131127-2                                        amd64        client-side GPU offloading for NVIDIA Optimus
```

I think this means that I have the drivers installed but my GPU is not being detected.

Some things that I have already done are installing cuda on this system
I have already installed the deb package using the following commands

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.5-18_amd64.deb 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

But now when I run any of the samples, like devicequery, it shows

```
cudaGetDeviceCount returned 38
-> no CUDA-capable device is detected
```

I have been through a number of other discussions but they are beyond my level of understanding. Can anybody please suggest what I should do next because I really need to install CUDA on this system. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you have both libcuda1-304 and libcuda1-352 together with the nvidia-304 driver!!!!!

firstly uninstall everything having "304" in it.

The following applies if you installed bumblebee and the nvidia driver
and not if you have installed nvidia-prime:

edit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf and change the lines:

line 22: >Driver=nvidia

line 55: >KernelDriver=nvidia-352

line 58: >LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-352:/usr/lib32/nvidia-352

line 61: >XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-352/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules

lastly you may have to

```
sudo "a-cuda-application"
```

at first in order to get cuda working for the first time and then you can use it without "sudo" for the rest of the session.